# XPath select input which occure before some div with different text

Tags: html, css, xpath

I got page with list of checkbox and labels assigned to them, its look like this:

```
x label1
x label2
x label3
```

As html it looks like this:

```
<div class="default-row">
    <span class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-329" tabindex="0" >
        <label for="gwt-uid-329"></label>
    </span> 
    <div class="row-label" title="out1">test1</div>
</div>
<div class="default-row">
    <span class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-321" tabindex="0" >
        <label for="gwt-uid-321"></label>
    </span> 
    <div class="row-label" title="out1">test2</div>
</div>
<div class="default-row">
    <span class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-322" tabindex="0" >
        <label for="gwt-uid-322"></label>
    </span> 
    <div class="row-label" title="out1">test3</div>
</div>
```

And what I would like to achieve is to be able to select checkbox with specific label. Currently I got something like this:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'test1')]//preceding::input[@type='checkbox'][1]
```

but somehow it is selecting me first and last elements. 'test1' text is only placeholder, I am aiming for same xPath for each checkbox with only different label. Any ideas?

I can not change/add any new class names or id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I just made some stupid mistake. Answer is:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'text1')]//preceding-sibling::span//input[@type='checkbox']
```

I will leave post. Maybe it will help someone. Cheers.

Comment: It would still be incorrect as the text you need to look for is **test1**

`//div[contains(text(), 'test1')]//preceding-sibling::span//input[@type='checkbox']`

Comment: It was just typo